# Erro search ion-searchbar

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic2

Boa noite a todos
Estou tendo um problema com um código de pesquisa e gostaria de ajuda.
Conforme você digita no campo de pesquisa, a lista muda e funciona normalmente, mas quando você exclui o que digitou, a lista não retorna com todos os elementos.
Alguém pode me ajudar?
Obrigado

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let topic of cuponsTotais">
      {{ topic.numerocupom }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Array: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  0:{numerocupom: "0620"}
  1:{numerocupom: "1109"}
  2:{numerocupom: "1441"}
  3:{numerocupom: "2810"}
  4:{numerocupom: "2827"}
  5:{numerocupom: "3141"}
  6:{numerocupom: "3260"}
  7:{numerocupom: "3715"}
  8:{numerocupom: "5104"}
  9:{numerocupom: "5613"}
 10:{numerocupom: "5632"}
 11:{numerocupom: "6037"}
  length:12
   **proto**:Array(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como está o seu método de filtrar `cuponsTotais`? Coloque para que possa tentar ajudar.
Mas basicamente você precisa resetar a lista. O filtro deve ser feito sobre a lista no seu estado inicial.

**EDIT**

Pelo seu código, é possível ver que o problema é que você está filtrando o cuponsTotais e jogando nele mesmo, ou seja, vc está alterando o valor da sua fonte de origem.

O ideal seria um localService ou algo do tipo. Mas simplificando aqui, digamos que você recebeu o response de uma API, e quer filtrar esse resultado localmente, sem precisar ficar chamando a API novamente.

Você pode fazer uma cópia do resultado quando popula o cuponsTotais (um dos jeitos que podem ser feitos, para "perder" a referência do objeto original).

```
this.cuponsFiltrados = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.cuponsTotais));
```

Use esse cuponsFiltrados para montar a sua lista no html. E o teu método de filtrar agora ficaria assim:

```
getTopics(ev: any) {
    let serVal = ev.target.value; 
    if (serVal && serVal.trim() != '') { 
        this.cuponsFiltrados = this.cuponsTotais.filter((topic) => { 
            return (topic.numerocupom.indexOf(serVal.toLowerCase()) > -1); 
        }) 
    } else {
        this.resetCupons(); 
    }
}

private resetCupons() {
    this.cuponsFiltrados = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.cuponsTotais));
}
```

Deve resolver.

Abraços!

Comment: Obrigado pela disponibilidade. Se puder ajudar será de boa valia. Segue o método.

Comment: Não prefere editar o post, e formatar? Fica mais fácil para visualizar...

Comment: Você foi cirúrgico na solução, estava tentando formatar mas não será necessário. Agradeço a ajuda. Sucesso!

Comment: @ClaudioJunior10 que bom que te ajudou, sucesso pra vc também! Se puder marcar a resposta como aceita, assim consigo ajudar outras pessoas também. Abraços!